# Multiplicative inverses of $\mathbb Z_x$

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question asks: Consider $\mathbb Z_3$. For each of its non-zero elements (namely $1$ and $2$), find a multiplicative inverse (if one exists).

To make sure I'm doing this correctly, I believe to find a multiplicative inverse of a non-zero element in $\mathbb Z_x$: as for any $r\in \mathbb Z_x$, finding $s\in \mathbb Z_x$ such that $rs = 1\pmod{x}$

So for this problem:

$\mathbb Z_3$:

$1 \cdot 1 = 1 = 1\pmod{3}$ so the mulitplicative inverse of $1$ is $1$.

$2 \cdot 2 = 4 = 1\pmod{3}$  so the multiplicative inverse of $2$ is $2$.

The problem says namely 1 and 2, so I'm just confused as to how many more I should do, or if I stop and am done? I guess I'm just confused as to when the problem is completely solved. Or, if I am even taking the right approach to this question.

Comment: You're all done. You may want to work out what happens in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for different values of $n$. The title of your question suggests that.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand my confusion now. Thank you Bernard.

Comment: You need to take into account the possibility that some numbers might not have any and that some numbers might have more than $1$.  And $0$ can never have one.  So... yes, you are done.  $0$ doesn't have one and there are only two other numbers and you tested them each.  So you are done.  But try $\mathbb Z_6$ (you'll be surprised)

Comment: @fleablood If I'm doing this correctly, in $\mathbb Z_4$, $2$ does not have a muliplicative inverse. Is this correct?

Comment: @fleablood A number can't have more than $1$ inverse. If an inverse exists then it is unique in $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.

Comment: @Trever Sturm, yes, you are right, $2$ doesn't have an inverse in $\mathbb{Z_4}$. In general there is a theorem that a number $a$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z_n}$ if and only if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, which means $gcd(a,n)=1$. But $gcd(2,4)=2$, so $2$ isn't invertible in $\mathbb{Z_4}$.

Comment: I didn't say a number *could* have two inverses.  I said you had to take that possibility into account.  Or prove it cant be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb{Z_3}=\{0,1,2\}$. Any other integer is equal to one of the elements of the set $\{0,1,2\}$ in $\mathbb{Z_3}$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a specific word for $\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: @Trever Sturm, I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "specific word"?